# How to log to rollbar

Tags: go, rollbar

There is a sample Go code on the rollbar.com web site which is supposed to illustrate how log items are supposed to be sent to Rollbar:

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/rollbar/rollbar-go"
)

func main() {
  rollbar.SetToken("6a...16")
  rollbar.SetEnvironment("production")                 // defaults to "development"
  rollbar.SetCodeVersion("v2")                         // optional Git hash/branch/tag (required for GitHub integration)
  rollbar.SetServerHost("web.1")                       // optional override; defaults to hostname
  rollbar.SetServerRoot("github.com/heroku/myproject") // path of project (required for GitHub integration and non-project stacktrace collapsing)

  result, err := DoSomething()
  if err != nil {
    rollbar.Critical(err)
  }

  rollbar.Info("Message body goes here")

  rollbar.Wait()
}
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't compile because the called `DoSomething` function doesn't exists. But even if I fix this issue and create a function called `DoSomething` then it still doesn't log anything into Rollbar.

How should I log to Rollbar from a Go code?

Comment: DoSomething is meant to be a placeholder for your code. When you implemented DoSomething, did you make it return a error?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I did return an error. But regardless of returning an error or not, the rollbar.Info(...) still should log something. But it doesn't. (If I was the writer of the tutorial then I would write a sample code that is able to run in itself. It is not too difficult in this case, see my answer below.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a close-to-minimal code that logs into Rollbar from Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/rollbar/rollbar-go"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rollbar.SetToken("7135d6a90b1c4a6d9dbc736fb97d3816")
    rollbar.SetEnvironment("production")                 // defaults to "development"

    rollbar.Info("Message body goes here")
    rollbar.WrapAndWait(DoSomething)
}

func DoSomething() {
    var timer *time.Timer = nil
    timer.Reset(10) // this will panic
}
```